# Disable selection in TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I see there are ways to disable selection in a `ListView`, but I haven't seen anything for a `TreeView` or `Grid`.

My form is quite basic and looks like this:

[image: View of form]

Problem is someone can go click on any one of the labels and suddenly it looks like this:

[image: View of form after selection]

How can I disable this behaviour?

```
<TreeView Focusable="False">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeViewItem Focusable="False">
        <TreeViewItem.Header>Group Header</TreeViewItem.Header>
        <TreeViewItem.IsExpanded>true</TreeViewItem.IsExpanded>
        <Grid Focusable="False">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Message ID">
                <Grid.Row>0</Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column>0</Grid.Column>
            </Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=GroupHeader.MessageId}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.Column>1</Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Row>0</Grid.Row>
            </TextBox>
            <Label Content="Creation Date">
                <Grid.Row>1</Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column>0</Grid.Column>
            </Label>
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=GroupHeader.CreationDateTime}">
                <Grid.Row>1</Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column>1</Grid.Column>
            </DatePicker>
            <Label Content="Instructing Agent">
                <Grid.Row>2</Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column>0</Grid.Column>
            </Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=GroupHeader.InstructingAgent}">
                <Grid.Row>2</Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column>1</Grid.Column>
            </TextBox>
            <Label Content="Instructed Agent">
                <Grid.Row>3</Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column>0</Grid.Column>
            </Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=GroupHeader.InstructedAgent}">
                <Grid.Row>3</Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column>1</Grid.Column>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </TreeViewItem>
   <TreeViewItem>
        ...
   </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Using the `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle` just disables it on the actual item header, not the content within it it seems.

Update: I've tried as the comment from Chris W and the answer about setting the control template suggested, using the following:

```
<Style x:Key="StretchingTreeViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type local:StretchingTreeViewItem}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
      <Style>
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
              <Rectangle/>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:StretchingTreeViewItem}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <ToggleButton.Style>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                      <Border Background="Transparent" Height="16" Padding="5" Width="16">
                        <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Data="M0,0 L0,6 L6,0 z" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="#FF989898">
                          <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                          </Path.RenderTransform>
                        </Path>
                      </Border>
                      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                          <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                            <Setter.Value>
                              <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                          </Setter>
                          <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF595959"/>
                          <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF262626"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                          <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF1BBBFA"/>
                          <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                          <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                          </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                          <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF262626"/>
                          <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF595959"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
              </Style>
            </ToggleButton.Style>
          </ToggleButton>
          <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ContentPresenter Focusable="False" x:Name="PART_Header" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
          </Border>
          <ItemsPresenter Focusable="False" x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
          </Trigger>
          <!--<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
          </Trigger>-->
          <!--<MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
              <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
          </MultiTrigger>-->
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The result is the text on the `TreeViewItem` itself is no longer selectable/doesn't get highlighted, but the contents within it still can be.

I've tried setting everything I can think of to `Focusable="False"` but that doesn't work either, so I am starting to think it isn't related to focus on an item. Especially since if you have nested `TreeViews` you can have both an inner and an outer item selected at the same time.

Comment: It will be in the default control template as a multitrigger on the nested ToggleButton for the item style isselected. I couldn't seem to find just a default wpf treeview item style and am too lazy to go make a wpf proj just to pull one out but if you want to share one it's pretty easy to spot it in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to remove the blue highlight while still being able to interact with the underlying controls using this TreeView Style:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.resoureces">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />
    <Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid Width="15" Height="13" Background="Transparent">
                        <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="1,1,1,1" Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}" Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle Margin="0,0,0,0" StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Opacity="0"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press"/>
                        <Border Name="Bd" Grid.Column="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="HasHeader" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header" Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="HasHeader" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header" Property="MinHeight" Value="19"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <!--<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>-->
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

AS you can see the place I made a change is commenting out the following.

```
                <!--<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>-->
```

Comment: This is the only solution to work for me so far, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As I believe you noticed yourself, the way to disable selection of a particular `TreeViewItem` is to set it's `Focusable` property to `false`. You've achieved partial success utilizing `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle` - this resulted in disabling selection of the first-level items, but not the nested ones. This is caused by the way a `TreeView` is designed.

`TreeView` is basically an `ItemsControl` which wraps it's items with `TreeViewItem` containers. The key thing here is that it only contains it's children (first-level items), so the `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle` is only applied to it's children - hence your results.

`TreeViewItem` also derives from `ItemsControl`, and it contains it's own children, so all second-level items are children (and items) of their first-level parents, etc. `TreeViewItem` also wraps all it's children with `TreeViewItem` containers - in your case, the `Grid` inside the `TreeViewItem` called "Group Header" is wrapped with `TreeViewItem`, which you can confirm using tools like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). So in order to disable selection of second-level items, you should set `TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle` of all corresponding first-level parent items as you did with your `TreeView`.

Surely when dealing with multi-level trees it may become problematic to explicitly set `TreeViewItem.ItemConainerStyle` for all items, so you can utilize implicit style:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    ...
</TreeView>
```

Now this style will be applied to all `TreeViewItem` controls (w.r.t. implicit styling rules) within the `TreeView` - importantly, not only the first-level ones. This should get you the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says there are two triggers in the default `ControlTemplate` of the `TreeViewItem` that changes the look of an item when its selected.

By removing those triggers you can achieve what you want:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewProblem2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewProblem2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Fill" Color="#FF595959"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Stroke" Color="#FF262626"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Stroke" Color="#FF27C7F7"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Fill" Color="#FFCCEEFB"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Stroke" Color="#FF1CC4F7"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Fill" Color="#FF82DFFB"/>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="TreeArrow" Figures="M0,0 L0,6 L6,0 z"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Fill" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Stroke" Color="#FF818181"/>
        <Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Background="Transparent" Height="16" Padding="5,5,5,5" Width="16">
                            <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Data="{StaticResource TreeArrow}" Fill="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Fill}" Stroke="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Stroke}">
                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                            </Path>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Fill}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.Static.Checked.Stroke}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Stroke}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Fill}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Stroke}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItem.TreeArrow.MouseOver.Checked.Fill}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"/>
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TreeView Focusable="False">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeViewItem Focusable="False">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>Group Header</TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TreeViewItem.IsExpanded>true</TreeViewItem.IsExpanded>
                <Grid Focusable="False">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="Message ID">
                        <Grid.Row>0</Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column>0</Grid.Column>
                    </Label>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=GroupHeader.MessageId}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.Column>1</Grid.Column>
                        <Grid.Row>0</Grid.Row>
                    </TextBox>
                    <Label Content="Creation Date">
                        <Grid.Row>1</Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column>0</Grid.Column>
                    </Label>
                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=GroupHeader.CreationDateTime}">
                        <Grid.Row>1</Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column>1</Grid.Column>
                    </DatePicker>
                    <Label Content="Instructing Agent">
                        <Grid.Row>2</Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column>0</Grid.Column>
                    </Label>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=GroupHeader.InstructingAgent}">
                        <Grid.Row>2</Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column>1</Grid.Column>
                    </TextBox>
                    <Label Content="Instructed Agent">
                        <Grid.Row>3</Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column>0</Grid.Column>
                    </Label>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=GroupHeader.InstructedAgent}">
                        <Grid.Row>3</Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column>1</Grid.Column>
                    </TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This will apply to all `TreeViewItem`s. I'd put these in a `ResourceDictionary` and then just pull them in from there.

One way to obtain the default `ControlTemplate` for editing is to use Blend. Here is the option:

[image: Blend Editing Template]

Comment: Ok, after trying this out all this does is disable selection of the headers, but it does not disable selection of contents.

Comment: I beg to differ, tried it out with your specific code. Updated the code with the whole version I'm using. I am not able to select the `TreeViewItem` by clicking on the label in the grid.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I'm targeting the latest .NET framework (4.6.1) (Windows 10, VS2015)

Comment: I'm using 4.5 on Windows 7. I've even tried copying the executable to a machine running Windows 8 and that had the same problem.

Comment: After work when I get home I'll try to figure out what might be the difference. Time for a VM running Win7 :)

Comment: I'd be really interested to see what's causing this... but I'm doubtful it is the OS that would do it. I've been wrong before though :D

Comment: Working on Win7, .NET Framework 4.5 as well. Here might be some misunderstanding of what "not working" means in my opinion. For me "working" means that when you click on the label "Message ID" for example the `TreeViewItem` doesn't get selected, but when clicking inside the controls those work properly just like before. Anyway, I see you already accepted a different answer, which is basically the same as this with some additional triggers (which I don't know why are there, because the default `TreeViewItem` template doesn't contain them)

Comment: Could you upload your project file where it is working? Maybe I did something stupid. By not working I mean I had the same behaviour I had before trying anything, where labels got highlighted.

Comment: Sure, here's the whole thing: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwb6Bsfrx94pUWlFZENPY0ZSWEk/view?usp=sharing   Then again, it might be me who did something stupid, but this truly works for me :) If this won't work for you, then I don't get it. Even tried changing the theme in Windows to check if it has something to do with that, but it was still working for me.

Comment: Soooo your project is working for me... this is weird. It must be something else I've done somewhere in the depths of this monstrosity I'm making. Thank you for the effort though! I wish I could give a split of the bounty :(